# Prove that $V=X\cap(Y\setminus U)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

This is an exercise page 7 from Sutherland's book Introduction to Metric and Topological Spaces.

> Suppose that $V,X,Y$ are sets with $V\subseteq X\subseteq Y$ and suppose that $U$ is a subset of $Y$ such that $X\setminus V=X\cap U$.
>
> Prove that $V=X\cap(Y\setminus U)$.

My attempt:

Let $x\in X\cap(Y\setminus U)$. Then $x\in X$ and $x\in Y\setminus U$. So, $x\in X$ and $x\notin U$.

Here the solution given by Sutherland's book argues differently. So I am wondering if I can say: If an element $x$ is in the set $X$ then we can write $x\in V$ and $x\in X\cap V$.

And continuing, we have $x\in V$ and $x\in X\cap V$ and $x\notin U$.

The last two relations can be eliminated. And hence, $x\in V$.

The second part of the proof is to prove conversely that $V\subseteq X\cap(Y\setminus U)$.

I am wondering if the first part of my proof is valid, especially the second sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your proof is not valid. The assumption that $x\in X$ does *not* imply that $x \in V$ and $x \in X \cap V$. For instance, take the sets $V=\{1,2,3\}$ and $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then $4 \in X$, but $4 \notin V$ and $4 \notin V\cap X$. It might help to argue by contradiction for this direction (though it can also be proved directly).

Comment: Actually it is true here that $x\in V$ from the first line. The OP just didn't explain him/herself very well.

Comment: I think it takes a bit of arguing. Why do you say it is true from the first line?

Comment: Because in the first line (under the block) the OP found that $x\in X$ and $x\not \in U$. We are now just one small step (which the OP ommits) away from showing that $x\in V$.

Comment: I agree that it's just a few steps away, but that doesn't make my answer any less valid. The OP stated "So I am wondering if I can say: If an element $x$ is in the set $X$ then we can write $x\in V$ and $x\in X\cap V$." I answered "no" and explained why his/her logic was faulty.

Comment: I know. I just commented so the OP doen't get the idea that $x$ won't ultimately end up to be in $V$, in this particular case. The general notion that $x\in X\implies x\in V $ remains false, of course.

Comment: @kccu Thank you for your answer. I checked my proof and it seems I had made a typo. Now, it's corrected; obviously  you were right (what I typed earlier was wrong).

Comment: @johnny09 Now you have written "If an element $x$ is in the set $X$ then we can write $x\in V$ and $x\in X\cap U$." This is still false. By assumption, $X\cap U=X\setminus V$, so it's impossible to have $x \in X\cap U$ and $x \in V$. You can write $X= (X\cap V)\cup (X\cap V^C)=V\cup (X\setminus V)=V\cup (X\cap U)$, so $x \in X$ implies $x \in V$ _or_ $x \in X \cap U$...

Comment: Okay, thank you very much (also for the understanding). I have rolled back my edit so that it doesn't invalidate the given answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You start to reason in circles beyond the point "So I am wondering if I can say:..."

You need to keep in mind what you are trying to do. Namely you want to show that $x\in X\cap (Y\backslash U)\implies x\in V$. So once you've showed that $x\in V$ you can just stop. If I were your teacher I would ask you to elaborate on why $x\in V$ if $x\in X$ and $x\not \in U$. (Can you do that?)  It is true, however you just say it is. I think any teacher would want you to explain why.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me if you need help to prove $V\subseteq X\cap (Y\backslash U)$. If you do, just say where you need help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, I do not need help for the second part. I wanted to show that I understand the proof is consisted of two parts. Nevertheless, thank you. I do not quite understand what you mean "reason in circles". I try to express $x\in X$ in a different way and continue to the objective which is to prove that $X\cap(Y\setminus U)\subseteq V$. Also in your third sentence it should be an intersection, not a union.

Comment: Well for instance. In the third line from below you reach the conclusion "and hence $x\in V$. But the line above that one starts with "we have $x\in V$. You can say anything you want in between, but if you start with $x\in V$, then of course  you can say (hence) $x\in V$ again at any point you like. The important part is, why $x\in V$ in the first place. (See the last sentence of my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Using $+$ to mean union, and multiplication to mean intersection,and $-$ for complement (That is $a-b=a\backslash b$) we have $$V=X-(X-V).$$ We also have $$X-V=X U \;\text  { and } X=X Y.$$  Hence $$V=X-(X-V)=X-X U=( X Y) -( X Y)U=X(Y-Y U)=X(Y-U)=$$ $$=X\cap (Y\backslash U).$$ Note that the condition $U\subset Y$ was unnecessary.